# Android: Async task returns null,even when working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Good Morning All,

I have an Async task that downloads a picture from the internet.  I have three buttons with names on them, and if an different name than the one already downloading is pressed, I want it to cancel the task and start one with the new name.

```
DownloadImageTask downloadPicTask = null;
int tasksRunning;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail, container, false);

    fillData();




    return rootView;

}



public void fillData(){

    if(downloadPicTask != null){
        Log.i(TAG,"Trying to cancel task...");
        downloadPicTask.cancel(true);
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG,"why why why");
    }


    ... 

    downloadPicTask = new DownloadImageTask(imageView);
    downloadPicTask.execute(firstName,lastName);

tasksRunning = tasksRunning + 1;
    Log.i(tag,String.valueOf(tasksRunning));    
    ...


}



private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    boolean canceled = false;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
       Log.i(TAG, "Async Cancelled");
        canceled = true;

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        ... //downloading the bitmap here

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(!canceled){
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    }


}
```

For some reason,  once the first task has begun and I press a different name, downloadPicTask  returns null, therefore it won't cancel. ***This happens only the first cancel try!***  Even thought the task returns null, it runs properly, and sets the imageview when finished. Subsequent tries to cancel the task are succesful, as after the first time downloadPicTask no longer returns null.

Anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: When you start the activity, it calls `fillData()` with `downloadPicTask == null`; hence the 'why why why' log. I see no issue here.

Comment: this might be something you want to try: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader (depending on what exactly you want to achieve)

Comment: @etienne  Sorry if my post was not clear.  When the fragment is created the task is null.  However, fillData() is then called, and my problem is when the button is pushed and fillData() is called the second time.

Comment: Well, if you are absolutely positive the line is printed twice, it must come from a part of the code you didn't post (with `downloadPicTask = null;`)

Comment: In an effort to figure out what is going on I added a "tasksRunning" counter.  The log notification shows a 1 count twice, once for the initial onCreate and once for the fillData() called when the button is pushed for the first time.  After that the counter increases once per button push.

Comment: Is it possible that my troubles are caused by how fillData() is called?  The first time it's called it is in the onCreate() in the fragment.  After that, the call is being made directly from the activity.  I've tried adding context, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The `cancel()` method of AsyncTask will not interrupt your `doInBackground()` method, it will merely cause `onCancelled()` to be called instead of `onPostExecute()` once your `doInBackground()` method returns. If you want to be able to cancel the execution of `doInBackground()` you'll need to periodically call `isCancelled()` in your `doInBackground()` method and return early if you detect a cancel state.

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on the `cancel()` method for further information.

Comment: I understand this concept.  The problem with my situation is that the second time fillData() is called it does not recognize there is already a task running, therefore downloadPicTask returns null and   downloadPicTask.cancel(true); is never called.

Comment: To add to that...  The first time fillData is called it's from onCreateView() of the fragment.  Subsequent calls are all made from the housing Activity, and do not recognize that the task already running.

Comment: Is the second call to `fillData()` being made before the first completes? If so, then maybe you need to make it `synchronized`, if not, then `downloadPicTask` should not be null.

Comment: Instead of `AsyncTask`, why not use `AsyncTaskLoader`? `LoaderManager` can keep track of different `Loader` instances based upon IDs rather than having references which may not be available if a new `Fragment` is created. By using the same ID across all instances of a particular `Fragment`, you can always check whether a `Loader` exists for that ID.

Comment: The second call is made before the first completes, but if I call it a third time it does properly cancel the second, and so on and so on.  The only time it returns null is the first.

Comment: In that case add a `synchronized` block or use some other mechanism to ensure that the second call does not occur until after the first call to `fillData()` has returned, then everything will work as it should.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I will investigate a synchronized block as well as AsyncTaskLoader as options.

Comment: The problem with synchronized is that I don't want the first call to finish.  That task is setting a picture that is now incorrect because the user chose a newer selection, prompting the second call of fillData().  I will look into using a AsyncTaskLoader instead.